# Hibernate MySQL: Code throws SQLGrammarException

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp

I'm trying to access a list of Members from a MySQL table from a JSP through Hibernate 4.1.

I'm getting this exception in my page whenever I execute the code.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /home.jsp:27
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
    for the right syntax to use near '.members members0_' at line 1
```

The detailed exception shows the following line as the culprit...

```
List<Members> result = ses.createQuery( "from Members" ).list();
```

My `Members.hbm.xml` is as follows...

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.stichon.ets.db.Members" table="members" catalog="stiadmin_ets">
    <id name="idMembers" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_members" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="initials" type="string">
        <column name="`initials`" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="`first_name`" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="`last_name`" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="mobile" type="string">
        <column name="`mobile`" length="15" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <set name="notificationses" table="notifications" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="id_member" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.stichon.ets.db.Notifications" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Adding "`" (back-tick) to column names hasnt helped.... :(

UPDATE: SQL Query in log files.

```
Hibernate: select devices0_.`idDevices` as idDevices1_0_, devices0_.`name` as name2_0_, devices0_.`desc` as desc3_0_ from stiadmin_ets.stiadmin_ets.`devices` devices0_
```

I see 2 issues here

1. Its appending 0_ to the table name, 1_0_ to the 1st field, 2_0_ to the 2nd and so on.
2. Its appending additional DB name stiadmin_ets.stiadmin_ets. May have something to do with catalog attrib in the hbm files. will check...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Issue resolved. I was using MySQLDialect instead of MySQL5Dialect. Stupid of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad!

Issue resolved. I was using MySQLDialect instead of MySQL5Dialect. Also removed the default_schema from the main cfg xml.